# ¿Cambiar un valor boolean cada minuto?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una base de datos en Firebase (Fire Store) donde hay un campo con un Boolean, lo que necesito es que cada minuto  que pase el valor cambie de True a False.

Comment: Hola AS, ¿como estas?, hay varias cosas que te están faltando aquí, empezando con [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), hasta algo tan simple como ¿que lenguaje o plataforma estas usando para consumir la API? ¿Android, JavaScript, python, etc.? Un saludo.

Comment: PD: ¡¡Te invito a modificar tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte!!